# Entity framework core adds quotes to function name

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, .net-core, entity-framework-core

I am using EF Core in my project and i want to use the property **DbFunction**.
I declared my function like this :

```
[DbFunction]
    public static string int_to_str(int CODE)
    {
        throw new NotSupportedException();
    }
```

then I used this :

```
var list = _dbContext.Ccy
            .Select(c => new Ccy{ Code = DbContext.int_to_str(c.Code), Name = c.Name })
            .ToList();
```

but every time it adds automatically quotes to the name of the function and i get as putput

```
Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Database.Command:Error: Failed executing DbCommand (12ms) [Parameters=[], CommandType='Text', CommandTimeout='0']
SELECT "int_to_str"("c".CODE) AS "Code", "c".LIBELLE AS "Name" FROM TABLE2 "c"
Devart.Data.Oracle.OracleException (0x80004005): ORA-00904: "int_to_str": invalid identifier
```

So it's obvious that the problem is the double quotes but I don't know why it adds them

Comment: Which EF Core version are you using?

Comment: Can you please try EF Core 2.1?

Comment: The more important question is which Oracle provider are you using, because that behavior is controlled by the provider, not EF Core infrastructure. If you are using the sample EF Core Oracle provider, then the reason is [this line of code](https://github.com/aspnet/EntityFrameworkCore/blob/release/2.2/samples/OracleProvider/src/OracleProvider/Query/Sql/Internal/OracleQuerySqlGenerator.cs#L196). Since this provider is unsupported, you can't ask for fix I guess. For now, try specifying the method name in uppercase, (or exactly the way it's defined in the db),  e.g. `[DbFunction("INT_TO_STR")]`

Comment: @viveknuna I am using EF Core 2.1

Comment: Tahnks @IvanStoev specifying the name of the function between quotes and uppercase actually worked :) 
I tried to define it the same way in the db but that way doesn't work